# App Architecture with Durandal

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

I have an application built with DurandalJS with the following:

1. **Index.html**: Default base page
2. **Shell.js**: The shell - contains a menu
3. **intro.js**: viewmodel is rendered within the shell if the user is not authenticated
4. **home.js**: viewmodel is rendered within the shell if the user is authenticated

My authentication code is called from shell.js.

I need my shell to be able to monitor some properties in the intro.js and home.js files.  Specifically - if a user selects an item with a checkbox in one of those views, I need to have shell.js to change the menu items.  Ideally this can be done by allowing shell to "observe" stuff in the viewmodels.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem time ago. I used Durandal events to implement the comunicantion beetween the shell an the other views.

You can find the information about Durandal events in the next link: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Events/

I guive you an example, because the documentation is not very clear.

To throw an event in durandal you have to use the app module:

```
app.trigger("someEvent");
```

To catch this event, you have to do that:

```
app.on("someEvent", function () {
  //Do that you want
});
```

Also, this comunication can be implemented storing information in local storage or something like that, but I think that using events is more clear.

If somebody can give any other solution to this problem it would be great.

Comment: Thank you.  Any thoughts on knockout's pub/sub here?  http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html

Comment: I have just read your link, I think that is also very interesting, I will look that more deeply after. But I think that the durandal events module is easier to use, and if you are using durandal, make sense to use that module. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using pub/sub from here: 
 knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html

My fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/38/

```
/* Pub/sub code */
var postbox = new ko.subscribable();

ko.subscribable.fn.publishOn = function(topic) {
    this.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        postbox.notifySubscribers(newValue, topic);
    });

    return this; //support chaining
};

ko.subscribable.fn.subscribeTo = function(topic) {
    postbox.subscribe(this, null, topic);

    return this;  //support chaining
};

/* Selection code */
this.selectedItems = ko.observableArray().subscribeTo("TOPIC");

var viewModel = {
    documents: [{"documentId": "1"}, {"documentId": "2"}, {"documentId": "3"}],
    selectedDocumentIds: ko.observableArray()
};

viewModel.documentIndex = {};
ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.documents, function(doc) {
   viewModel.documentIndex[doc.documentId] = doc; 
});

this.selectedDocuments = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(viewModel.selectedDocumentIds(), function(id) {
        return viewModel.documentIndex[id];
    });
}).publishOn("TOPIC");

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```